# How do I show syntax coloring and scoping on Eclipse IDE?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

Currently my Eclipse IDE shows no syntax coloring and does not scope (*i.e.* suggest commands based on current text.) I've read the manual (bit.ly/1ZJVGRE) and couldn't find anything that worked.

Here is a picture of what my Eclipse editor currently looks like,
[image]

and here is a picture of my syntax color settings.
[image]

I am using Eclipse Mars C/C++ on Windows 8.1. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably opened the file with the Text Editor instead of the C/C++ editor. Eclipse opens the file with the last editor that was used to edit the file.

In the Project Explorer window, right-click on the file and choose 
**Open With -> C/C++ Editor**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that the editor thinks the current file is a C or C++ file

in the eclipse menu

1. click `window` to expand
2. click `preferences` to select
3. click `C/C++` to expand
4. click `editor` to expand
5. click `syntax coloring` to select
6. click `enable senamic highlighting` to enable syntax coloring
7. modify `element` items as desired (`Preview` window will tell you the current/result of any changes you make)
8. click `ok`